# iter() not working with datetime.now()

Tags: python, datetime, python-3.6, iterable

A simple snippet in Python 3.6.1:

```
import datetime
j = iter(datetime.datetime.now, None)
next(j)
```

returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

instead of printing out the classic `now()` behavior with each `next()`.

I've seen similar code working in Python 3.3, am I missing something or has something changed in version 3.6.1?

Comment: Interesting, I'd expect this to work. It works in 3.4 and 3.5 too.

Comment: It works when you replace `datetime.datetime.now` with `lambda: datetime.datetime.now()` or `partial(datetime.datetime.now)`.

Comment: I guess you should report this at their [bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/).

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is definitely a bug introduced in Python 3.6.0b1.  The `iter()` implementation recently switched to using `_PyObject_FastCall()` (an optimisation, see [issue 27128](http://bugs.python.org/issue27128)), and it must be this call that is breaking this.

The same issue arrises with other C `classmethod` methods backed by Argument Clinic parsing:

```
>>> from asyncio import Task
>>> Task.all_tasks()
set()
>>> next(iter(Task.all_tasks, None))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
StopIteration
```

If you need a work-around, wrap the callable in a `functools.partial()` object:

```
from functools import partial

j = iter(partial(datetime.datetime.now), None)
```

I filed [issue 30524 -- *iter(classmethod, sentinel) broken for Argument Clinic class methods?*](http://bugs.python.org/issue30524) with the Python project. The fix for this has landed and is part of 3.6.2rc1.

Comment: +1, but as a point of interest, why would you prefer `partial` to something like, say, a `lambda` (like in your comment)?

Comment: @erip: because it is *faster*. There is no Python frame to be created, the C implementation can call the `datetime.datetime.now` C function directly.

Answer (score 16):

I assume you're using CPython and not another Python implementation. And I can reproduce the issue with CPython 3.6.1 (I don't have PyPy, Jython, IronPython, ... so I can't check these).

The offender in this case is the replacement of [`PyObject_Call`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.5.3/Objects/iterobject.c#L216) with [`_PyObject_CallNoArg`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Objects/iterobject.c#L217) in the C equivalent of the `callable_iterator.__next__` (your object is a `callable_iterator`) method.

The `PyObject_Call` does return a new `datetime.datetime` instance while `_PyObject_CallNoArg` returns `NULL` (which is roughly equivalent to an exception in Python).

Digging a bit through the CPython source code:

The `_PyObject_CallNoArg` is just a macro for [`_PyObject_FastCall`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Include/abstract.h#L346-L347) which in turn is a macro for [`_PyObject_FastCallDict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Include/abstract.h#L343-L344).

[This `_PyObject_FastCallDict` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Objects/abstract.c#L2273-L2326) checks the type of the function (`C`-function or Python function or something else) and delegates to [`_PyCFunction_FastCallDict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Objects/methodobject.c#L153-L269) in this case because `datetime.now` is a C function.

Since `datetime.datetime.now` has the `METH_FASTCALL` flag it ends up in the fourth `case` but there [`_PyStack_UnpackDict`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Objects/methodobject.c#L246) returns `NULL` and the function is never even called.

I'll stop there and let the Python devs figure out what's wrong in there. @Martijn Pieters already filed a Bug report and they will fix it (I just hope they fix it soonish).

So it's a Bug they introduced in 3.6 and until it's fixed you need to make sure the method isn't a `CFunction` with the `METH_FASTCALL` flag. As workaround you can wrap it. Apart from the possibilities @Martijn Pieters mentioned there is also a simple:

```
def now():
    return datetime.datetime.now()

j = iter(now, None)
next(j)  # datetime.datetime(2017, 5, 31, 14, 23, 1, 95999)
```

Comment: Great answer too, with added insight into the culprits. I'll keep the accepted mark on Martijn's answer as he's already submitted the issue with the Python project.

Comment: It's a confirmed bug in the FASTCALL optimisations, and Victor Stinner has a preliminary patch out at https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/1886