# Append function won't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I wrote a messy code part but I faced a problem that I couldn't understand so when I do :

```
x = 4
Number = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]
List = []
while x <= 0 :
    List.append(Number[x] * 2)
    x -= 1
```

But the problem that :

```
print(List) ===> []
```

not :

```
print(List) ===> [ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]
```

I wanna also Thank you for your helpful suggestion , and keep in mind that I am just Python Starter :D

Comment: `while x<=0` is never true, because `x` starts as 4.

Comment: I am not sure what this code is for, but you could also just do `new_list = [2 * xi for xi in Number]`

Comment: Why assume that it is Python that is broken (i.e. that `.append` doesn't work) when Occam's razor says a much simpler explanation is that the logic is incorrect?

Comment: @SethMMorton Lol, yep. That's a good point. I see at least 5-10 questions posted each day where the OP is claiming that Python is broken in some way, and there code is bug-free. Of course there are [cases where the OP is actually right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44283540/iter-not-working-with-datetime-now), but more those are few and far between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned by @Zack Tarr you need to tell the while loop when to start and end.
However, there is a much cleaner approach to iteration:

```
#Only use camel case for class names
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

#Good job avoiding shadowing of "list"
lst = []

for number in numbers:
    lst.append(number*2)
```

This is equivalent to using:

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
lst = []
for i in range(len(numbers)):
    number = numbers[i]
    lst.append(number*2)
```

As mentioned by @Christian Dean, an even more pythonic solution would be to use something like:

```
lst = [number * 2 for number in numbers]
```

This one-liner works by iterating like we did before and creating a list out of all "number * 2"s.

Python is a great language, good luck!

Comment: Yes, iteration by value and not index is more Pythonic. But even better would be to use a list comprehension `lst = [x * 2 for x in range(1, 6)]` :-)

Comment: @ChristianDean You're right, however, "one-liners" are a lot more confusing to beginners. Altho there a good thing to learn, I'll edit my answer to mention you're method :-)

Answer (score 2):

I will not answer the direct question (other answers do that), but I will give you as suggestion on how to debug things like this.  Simply toss in some `print` statements:

```
x = 4
Number = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]
List = []
print('Before the loop')
while x <= 0 :
    print('Inside loop, x =', x)
    List.append(Number[x] * 2)
    print('Contents of List = ', List)
    x -= 1
print('After the loop')
```

Had you run this, you would have observed that nothing inside the loop was printed, and you would have known to check your logic for the `while` loop.

Comment: Of course if his program was bigger, it would probably be faster and cleaner to use a real debugger (e.g Python's `pdb` module).

Comment: Considering the audience here, I think recommending a debugger would be overkill.

Comment: Yes, I agree. However, as I said in my previous comment, when the OP starts to create bigger programs it will become tedious to put `print` calls everywhere. Yes there would be a learning curve for to a debugger, but the long term gain would far outweigh that.

Comment: Thanks for the tip of spamming print command as I am just a starter in Python , and I will check the pdb debugger sounds good :D

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, your condition on the `while` loop is `False`.
Anyway, for this purpose, a `while` loop is not the best solution, a `for` is better, list comprehensions are the best:

`List = [i * 2 for i in Number]`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a commend you need to update the while loop. Also I would not name a var `List` as it is very close to predefined word in python `list`.

```
x = 4
Number = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]
lst= []
while x >= 0 :
    lst.append(Number[x] * 2)
    x -= 1
```

Comment: yep , I saw that , a pretty silly mistake from a dumb python starter thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change the < to a >, like this:

```
x = 4
Number = [1 , 2 , 3 , 4 , 5]
List = []
while x >= 0 :
    List.append(Number[x] * 2)
    x -= 1
print(List)

#output
[10, 8, 6, 4, 2]
```

The way your current program is written, the while loop never begins. The initial check to see if x <= 0 fails, because you have defined x as 4. If you update the check to say: while x **>=** 0, the loop starts because the initial condition is true.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is that x starts off as greater than 0, but your while condition is x <= 0.